# Automatically scale Axon's tracking event processors

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

I am using Axon framework 4.0.3 with Spring Boot to have event sourcing, and have one tracking processor which is configured to have multiple segments/threads to process events concurrently:

```
axon.eventhandling.processors[my_processor].initial-segment-count = 6
axon.eventhandling.processors[my_processor].thread-count = 3
```

It is meant to have 2 nodes of `my_processor` using 3 threads each.

However, the problem with this solution is that it's not scalable. I have to know from the very beginning how many nodes and threads I must have, as it's not possible to change it later: if I increase the `initial-segment-count` and restart the processor, nothing happens. Even worse if I decrease the segment count: events that were meant for the "removed" segments are never processed!

Ideally it should be able to specify just the number of threads that each node should use. After that, when new nodes are added to the processor, the number of segments should scale up accordingly. Similarly if I remove nodes, the number of segments should scale down. Is this possible with Axon, or is it not designed to be scaled this way at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assumption from your part is completely right - just adjusting these fields is not scalable, *at runtime*.
This is exactly why we have introduced the Split and Merge operations, to split/merge segments at runtime of your Axon application. See [this](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/pull/969) GitHub pull request for it's introduction into the framework.

This feature will be part of Axon 4.1, which will be released today.
Do note that if you're only using the framework, this feature **does not** give you the automatic scaling. It will require implementation from your part, leveraging the provided split and merge API, to make it automatic.

[Axon Server](https://axoniq.io/product-overview/axon-server) on the other hand provides you with a split/merge button in the UI, thus relieving you of the necessity to build this yourself. 
I am fairly certain Axon Server will also introduce an auto scaling solution eventually, but not as part of release 4.1.

Hope this gives you some background Archie!

Comment: Great! Stay tuned Archie, I am working on getting the release in place for everybody as we speak.

Comment: is there an example anywhere you know of implementing this split/merge for a changing (auto-scaling) number of nodes/threads/JVMs? This seems like a fairly complex bit of plumbing that presents plenty of opportunity for applications to find uncovered manholes...

Comment: I do, but those are all directed at clients, thus not something I can share Added though, I am pretty sure the Axon User Group [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/axonframework] contains information about this too. And, if it's not there or on StackOverflow, a dedicated question asking for (pseudo)-code would be in place.